# Establishing database connection between node.js angular and mysql workbench

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, angular

Im learning from a ready application and im trying to make the connection so the app to start working and save data.

[picture of the hostname and port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po26N.jpg)

I done the connectin also make a 'employees database' with the two tables that I need

[picture of the schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ILKE.jpg)

The server is running on localhost 3000 and the front end is listening on port 4200. This is the code for the connection and creating the database/schema.

config.json

```
{
  "host": "localhost",
  "user": "cveto",
  "database": "employees",
  "password": "1234567"
}
```

database.js creating pool

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const config = require('../config/config.json');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: config.host,
  user: config.user,
  database: config.database,
  password: config.password,
});

module.exports = pool.promise();
```

And some query models

```
const db = require('../util/database');

module.exports = class Employee {
  constructor(names, address, number, salary) {
    this.names = names;
    this.address = address;
    this.number = number;
    this.salary = salary;
  }

  static fetchAll() {
    return db.execute('SELECT * FROM employees');
  }

  static save(employee) {
    return db.execute(
      'INSERT INTO employees (names, address, number, salary) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
      [employee.names, employee.address, employee.number, employee.salary]
    );
  }

  static delete(id) {
    return db.execute('DELETE FROM employees WHERE id = ?', [id]);
  }
};
```

I just want to know how I can make the connection so the app to work and save to my database the users and new employees. The code is from public repositority so the code is working, its now from the code its from tha database or server conncetion.

Comment: You should never make a direct connection between a web app and a database, because you will need to transfer the database credentials to the frontend so every possible attacker can read them. Usually you should use a backend to "protect" your database and have some authorization between frontend and backend. (Sorry for not answering the actual question)

Answer (score 0):

DB.js File

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 100,
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : '',
});


let myDb = {};

myDb.searchDataQ = (query) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.query(query, function (err, rows) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            resolve(rows)
        })
    });
};

module.exports = myDb;
```

Other JS File to execute

```
const db = require('../db/db');

function testMethod() {
    let query = 'SELECT * FROM employees';
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            resolve(await db.searchDataQ(query));
        } catch (e) {
            reject(0);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as an explanation or documentation citations.